# Shifting GNOME 3 notification corner to bottom-left!

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, gnome3, gnome-shell, notifications

I like that GNOME 3's <sub>(v3.4 on Ubuntu 12.04)</sub> 'Hot Corner' and 'notification corner (?)' response really fast, but the latter, for me, would have been better off at the bottom-left corner; leaving the bottom-right for other status menus, chat menus, etc. While reaching for such menus of the  full-sized windows, my cursor often touch the notification corner and the try is up instantly like you can see in the snapshots where I was meaning close the 'downloads' bar of my web browser.

[image: snap1]

[image: snap2]

Can I get the *Notification Corner* shifted to the bottom-left?

Comment: Untested: try this GNOME 3 extension: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/204/shell-notification-move/

Comment: Thanks for the link @slm. But unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work in Ubuntu 12.04